# Recursive copying the files

Tags: bash, shell

I have a directory structure like

```
# parent directory
dir/
```

Under this directory there are three sub directories:

```
dir1/dirA/dirB/
dir2/dirC/dirD/
dir3/dirE/dirF/
```

I wish to copy a file recursively into the first subdirectory only dir1/ dir2/ dir3/ only and not to its subdirectories dirA/ dirC/ dirE/ and so on i am using

```
find . -type d -exec cp filename.txt {} \;
```

but it is also copying the files into the 'dir2' and 'dir'. I used the `--min-depth` parameter but no success. Any idea?

Comment: Are you trying to `find` a file somewhere inside your given directory structure and then copy it into `dir1`?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to distinguish those directories, except by name (well, inode position, but that's not useful and _ick_).  If there's some distinguishing feature about that one subdirectory, you can search for that.  Otherwise, `./dir/dir1` and `./dir/dir2` are going to be too similar.

Comment: dir/ is the parent directory and it contains the file named as filename.txt and i am moving this to the dir1/ using the find . -type d -exec cp filename.txt {} \; but it gets copied into all the subsequent sub-directories

Comment: If you want it only in dir/dir1, you don't need a recursive copy.  If you want it in dir/dir1 and any sub-directories under that, then you can do it, but you obviously limit the `find` to the directory tree you're interested in: `find dir/dir1 ...`.

Comment: Sorry, but this question is not clear. Are you asking for the general solution to copy a file to the first directory found in the path? If it is the case, I must doubt it's usability, yet I can't think of any other reason to use such a complicated structure for such a simple task.

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -b --file-type | egrep "/$" | xargs -n 1 cp filename.txt
```

To explain, `egrep` is filtering directories from output, and then you pass it as parameter to the `cp` command. Of course keep in mind that filename.txt is in the CWD, or modify the path.

EDIT: This solution deals with spaces in the directory names.

Comment: @user3263699 have you found a solution to deal with spaces in the directory names. I couldn't do it using "find" command so I edited my answer to use "ls" instead.

Comment: I renamed the spaces like find -type d -exec rename '_' '.' {} \;

Answer (score 0):

If you have a file in `/dir/` and you want to copy it recursively to the tree of directories in `/dir/dir1`, you need to change the source directory in your find command to be /dir/dir1, like so:

```
find dir -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec cp /dir/filename.txt {} \;
```

If your pattern for copying files gets more difficult, instead of copying right from find, you could print out the possible variations with `-printf`. For example:

```
find dir -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf "cp %p\n"
```

Hope this helps.

Or, using bash syntax, you could skip find and say:

```
cd $dir; for d in dir1 dir2 dir3 ; do
  cp filename.txt $d
done
```

Or just use three copy statements.

Comment: With all due respect - WTF - if this is the answer he could just write "cp /dir/filename.txt /dir/dir1". It seems to me OP is searching for a different thing...

Comment: sounds like he wanted to copy into all subdirectories

Comment: I agree with Konzua. with that it will copy to recursively to all the sub-directories present in dir/dir1/ like dir/dir1/dirA dir/dir1/dirB. I need to restrict the copying only to dir1/ and not to its sub-directories.

Comment: @user3263699 sorry for spamming, but it IS a bit unclear what you're trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @memnoch_proxy - sorry for that. I didn't notice that it is copying to all of it's subfolders as well.